# Border-bottom com gradiente linear

Tags: css

Eu gostaria de estilizar uma borda para o h1, mas em gradiente linear, indo de cor x a cor y (ou transparência).

Eu utilizei pseudoclass (after), mas com a borda em gradiente eu não consigo fazer funcionar.

Alguém saberia me ajudar?

```css
h1:after {
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    border:2px solid #d0d0d0;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
```

```html
<h1>Título</h1>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assim ?

```css
.bot-left {
  position: relative;
}

.bot-left:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  
}

.bot-left:after {
  right: -3px;
  height: 3px;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(#000), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #000, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #000, transparent);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="bot-left"> Teste de Frase </h1>
```

Comment: Sim, exatamente isso! Pô cara, obrigado! :)

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer assim:

```css
h1:after {
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    border:2px solid #d0d0d0;
    box-shadow:1px 2px 3px #666;
}
```

```html
<h1>Título</h1>
```

Comment: Agradeço cara, mas no caso eu falo do gradiente indo da esquerda para direita, entendeu?! Ele começa com uma cor chapada e termina basicamente em outra cor chapada (ou transparência). :)